# HP-Unix: C-shell:Disk space checking

Tags: unix, hp-ux

I have 10 devices that using hp-ux and i want to check the disk space in each devices.
my requirement is if the space more than 90%, the info of device ans space will be save to a log.
this is list of device and ip address which i set as variable ipadd:

```
lo1 100.45.32.43
lot2 100.45.32.44
lot3 100.45.32.44
lot4 100.45.32.45
lot5 100.45.32.46 
and so on..
```

This is my script so far :

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set ipaddress = (`awk '{print $2}' "ipadd"`)
set device = (`awk '{print $1}' "ipadd"`)

@ j = 1
while ($j <= $#ipaddress)
   echo $ipaddress
   set i = 90        # Threshold set at 90%
   set max = 100
   while ($i <= $max)         
      rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | grep /dev/vg00 | grep $i% \
      |awk '{   file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6)); print "WARNING: $device[$j]:/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space." file ".file"}'    
      @ i++
   end
   @ j++
end
```

The output after bdf:

```
/dev/vg00/lvol2    15300207 10924582 28566314   79% /
/dev/vg00/lvol4      42529   23786   25510   55% /stand
```

The output at terminal after exec the script:

```
100.45.32.43
100.45.32.44
```

The output at .file:

```
WARNING: $device[$j]:/ has reached 79%. Perform HouseKeeping   IMMEDIATELY...
```

My question is, is it my looping have something wrong cause only iterates one time only because my .file output only show one device only?
And why $device[$j] not come out in .file output?
or awk have problem?

Thank you for the advice.